# unable to access to CP after setting cookie domain

Tags: login, admin, cookies, administration

Help! I was just trying to setting the cookie domain inside the CP > Admin > Security and Privacy > Cookie Settins

(as explained here [Cookie Settings](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/cookie_settings.html))

and now I can't login to the CP admin :(

how can solve this big problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, i've hardcoded the config.php with this:

```
$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_path'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$config['user_session_type'] = 'c';
$config['admin_session_type'] = 's';
```

Using an MSM installation this solution works great but the config.php has to have these set afterwards otherwise the CP lockout continues:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = "subdomain.mydomain.com";
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "myprefix";
$config['admin_session_type'] = 's';
```

Comment: Please, mark your answer as right. Thanks!